# Performance of replicateM in IO monad

Tags: performance, haskell, io, monads

I have an IO action called `action` in which I am doing a fairly heavy computation. I am using an IO monad in in order to have easy access to random numbers further down in the computation.

I also have the below functions which replicate the action and take the mean of the result. Because the action takes a fair amount of time to complete, I was wondering what the effect on the performance is from doing the sampling in this manner. Would it be better to do the sampling later in the evaluation so that parts of the program that are the same for each sample are not repeated or does the Haskell compiler optimise this already?

```
samp :: (Fractional b) => Int -> IO b -> IO b
samp n action = do
  samples <- replicateM n action
  return $ mean samples

mean :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> a
mean as =  s / (genericLength as)
  where s = sum as
```

Comment: Performance is something - a bit tricky in any language (I believe) - I worry less about your samplings than about your calculating the mean - it looks a bit like a space leak to me. When you (really) want performance it is best to do the coding and measuring thing and then optimize where necessary - "premature optimization" and Knuth you know

Comment: I see so analyse the code and then look for optimisation areas? Also could you explain why mean is a leak?

Comment: @BenJacob There can be a leak if `action` isn't strict enough that executing it forces the resulting value to be calculated. You could be building up a list of all the thunks to calculate leaking memory until `mean` forces them all.

Comment: Indeed, you are quite definitely building up the whole list. `replicateM` and `mapM` (or `traverse`) for many-element structures In `IO` have similar problems. To go modular, you really need to use a streaming library of some sort. In this case, what you're doing is simple enough to manage pretty easily with plain recursion, strictly accumulating sum and count by hand as you perform the actions.

Comment: It's hard to give a good answer without a concrete `action` and value for `n`.  If each `action` takes a few seconds and `n` is around 1000, a space leak isn't a concern.  Depending on `action`'s structure, "doing the sampling later" may or may not be helpful.  If you are using more than a handful of random numbers, you should be aware that `System.Random` is inappropriate for high-performance applications.  Etc., etc., etc.  Do you have a (possibly simplified) complete, runnable example you can provide?